# Using Custom View for trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to implement my custom-looking row action.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is what I've tried:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { action, view, completion in
            
        }
    
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Sil"
        label.font = .SemiBold.font12
        label.textColor = .Error.Error50


        // Create Attachment
        let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        imageAttachment.image = Assets.Icons.trashIcon
        // Set bound to reposition
        let imageOffsetY: CGFloat = 15.0
        imageAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 20, y: imageOffsetY, width: Assets.Icons.trashIcon.size.width, height: Assets.Icons.trashIcon.size.height)
        // Create string with attachment
        let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
        // Initialize mutable string
        let completeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
        // Add image to mutable string
        completeText.append(attachmentString)
        // Add your text to mutable string
        let textAfterIcon = NSAttributedString(string: "Sil")
        completeText.append(textAfterIcon)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.attributedText = completeText

        label.sizeToFit()
        
        action.image = UIImage(view: label)
        action.backgroundColor = .Error.Error20
        return
```

This is the result:

[image]

How can I achieve this properly?